# how to make signalr hub out from Form authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My MVC Website has a form authorization in web.config. Now all the page need to pass the authorization,so that they can be viewed.

But Now I have a console program (C# console program). This program need to send some message to SignalR Hub. But My signalR Hub is in my MVC Website,Now this C# console client can't send message to Signal Hub, Because My MVC Website has Form Authorization.

I want the console client doesn't need to be verified,but the pages in website need to be verified.

What Can I do with the website's web.config file?

[How to make the signalr client avoid form authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436996/how-to-make-the-signalr-client-avoid-form-authentication/27448194?noredirect=1#comment43389714_27448194)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply security on a folder using web.config file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810127/how-to-apply-security-on-a-folder-using-web-config-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same mechanism as for a normal folder, just use `<location path="signalr">`.

You need to be careful though as this exposes your hub to any non-authenticated call from the web as well. Maybe you'd be better with separate hubs so you can restrict the non-authenticated functionality to a minimum.

For more info on folder level securities see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871).